# How to set to heroku nextjs

Tags: next.js

I'm using this code in package.json and I want to deploy to heroku app

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "cd app && next build",
    "start": "npm run build && env NODE_ENV=production node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --ignore app/ app.js"   
},
```

I have also tried:

```
"start": "next start -p $PORT",
```

I'm using this boilerplate:
https://github.com/MustansirZia/next-express-bootstrap-boilerplate

Comment: currently im getting this...

https://test.herokuapp.com/_next/static/VprFLaLvekNmzlVsEkO_S/pages/index.js
and it shows a loading of page... and doesnt show the index

Comment: i had
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
"start": "npm run build && env NODE_ENV=production node app.js -p $PORT ",

Comment: Can you try changing the bottom line of app.js to start(port); while keeping port = process.env.PORT || 3000; at the top? Can you post your app.js code? And can you screenshot the page you see the link doesn't work very well

Comment: HI there thanks by the reply i have applied that and it works

Comment: i have set to 
    "start": "npm run build && env NODE_ENV=production node app.js -p $PORT",

Comment: sweet! I'll just put it as an answer for easy readability.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's running on the wrong port. Heroku will give you the port as an env variable, but your app needs to grab the port from the environment and then use it when starting up.

In app.js add this to the top (change that default port to whatever you want). It will grab the port from the environment variable PORT, or default to 3000 if it doesn't exist:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

Then at the very bottom, change the last line to this

```
start(port);
```